# Django logging errors into seperate files by timestamp

Tags: python, django, logging

I have set up a Django log successfully with the following code:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': 'debug.log',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

And from this, I'm able to find errors logged in the *'debug.log'* file that's define above.

However what I'd like to achieve is that any Django error is sent to an individual and timestamped log file. For example, if a ValueError is encountered, it would save it to a file named something like: *debug_2022-03-04_1143.log*

I searched some other answers on this, but most seemed to be talking about timestamping at logged intervals, and I couldn't find a solution to the objective I listed above. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: so, for something like this, i have to ask why you want to accomplish this

Comment: @bryan60 I have a small-scale setup with a small number of users. Errors are infrequent, and are looked at on a case-by-case basis. The system is being handed over, and I'd like to make the process of analysing errors easier for future operators.

Comment: if you want to make the process of analysing errors easier, then load your log files into a tool for analysing logs that makes them searchable and aggregates them. rather than putting them all into separate files.

Comment: @bryan60 appreciate the suggestion, however not the solution I'm after.

Comment: do you, but you'll probably have to write your own django logger implementation as this isn't something developers would usually want to do with their logs